# My Flask app is running on my local server, but it isn't running on Heroku. How is this possible?

Tags: python, flask, heroku, web-applications

These are my Build Logs. My app is showing an error.

```
2020-08-09T20:25:31.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded

2020-08-09T20:25:33.898890+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: gunicorn: command not found

2020-08-09T20:25:33.955046+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127

2020-08-09T20:25:33.996024+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed

2020-08-09T20:25:42.118494+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=imagen-iitb.herokuapp.com request_id=b4762bc9-5410-443d-a630-d6ea43891527 fwd="103.240.97.60" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

2020-08-09T20:25:48.479794+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting

2020-08-09T20:25:53.064583+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn run:app`

2020-08-09T20:25:55.106853+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: gunicorn: command not found

2020-08-09T20:25:55.149435+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127

2020-08-09T20:25:55.179854+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

This is my `requirements.txt`:

```
bcrypt==3.1.7
blinker==1.4
cffi==1.14.1
click==7.1.2
DateTime==4.3
email-validator==1.1.1
Flask==1.1.2
Flask-Bcrypt==0.7.1
Flask-Login==0.5.0
Flask-Mail==0.9.1
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.4.4
Flask-WTF==0.14.3
googleapis-common-protos==1.52.0
httplib2==0.18.1
idna==2.10
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.11.2
jws==0.1.3
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
oauth2client==3.0.0
ordereddict==1.1
Pillow==6.2.2
protobuf==4.0.0rc2
pyasn1==0.4.8
pyasn1-modules==0.2.8
pycparser==2.20
pycryptodome==3.4.3
Pyrebase==3.0.27
python-firebase==1.2
python-jwt==2.0.1
pytz==2020.1
requests==2.11.1
requests-toolbelt==0.7.0
rsa==4.5
six==1.15.0
SQLAlchemy==1.3.18
Werkzeug==1.0.1
WTForms==2.3.3
zope.interface==5.1.0
```

I can provide my code if you want it. Thank you.

Edit: My data is not getting updated into my SQL-Alchemy database file (site.db)

My app is online at: https://imagen-iitb.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to add the `gunicorn` library to your `requirements.txt`. Without gunicorn, the web app cannot start as it is the HTTP server. To fix this, just add `gunicorn==20.0.4` to your requirements.txt and it should work.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your prompt reply. I did not check my requirements.txt file property. Thanks for pointing out my silly mistake :)

Comment: No worries! Glad I could help